# checkbox gets checked even when value is empty with empty() function in PHP

Tags: php, html, checkbox, simplexml

I wrote this code:

```
 <?php if (!empty($isLocal)) {echo "checked";} ?>
```

Sounds simple? If $isLocal is not empty then check it otherwise don't check it.

Yet, it keeps checking it despite the empty value! What's wrong with this?!

I had to echo the isLocal a few times across the page and it remains the same - it's still empty yet the checkbox is checked. Yes, I looked at HTML code to see if "checked" is not written and it wasn't. It only prints "checked" inside the PHP logic.

the HTML code is this

```
Enable this machine:<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isLocal" 
<?php if (!empty($isLocal)) {echo "checked";} ?>  />
```

One more thing - I am loading isLocal from XML file using simplexml.

```
 $configurations = simplexml_load_file('configs.xml');

foreach ($configurations->xpath("/configurations") as $t)
{

$isLocal=$t->isLocal;   

 }
```

But you see, the thing is that it can see if it's empty or has a value. I cannot use "isset()" because it's ALWAYS set even with empty value.

Comment: Since the HTML isn't showing the checked attribute you're echo'ing out, it sounds like something else may be toggling the checkbox - is there any javascript on that page that might change things?

Comment: No Javascript. That's why I am puzzled. And if I echo "$isLocal" and it shows empty value before the checkbox, the checkbox still gets checked when it should be unchecked. I also echoed $isLocal after the checkbox and it's still empty.

Comment: Since the rendered HTML you look at when you view source isn't showing `checked`, then something else is checking the checkbox.  This could be your browsers session management, javascript, or something else.  This is not likely to be an issue with your PHP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just learned that by entering "var_dump($isLocal)" it shows that it's an object, not a simple data type!

Doing this after loading the XML object:

```
$isLocal=(string)$t->isLocal;
```

solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

do like this :

```
<form action="checked.php" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" value="1" name="isLocal"/> Enable this machine
<input type="submit" name="formSubmit" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php 
if (!empty($_POST['isLocal']))
{echo "checked";}
?>
```